# Different state database in Hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I read that the default state database of Hyperledger Fabric is LevelDB, and it can be changed to CouchDB.

Is it possible to select a completely different database technology for the state database, and if yes - how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not presently (as of v1.1.0), though there is community interest in adding more databases such as PostgresQL or MySQL. The project welcomes contributions of this sort.

Comment: Do you have a starting point for digging deeper into the topic, e.g. where to read more about the community interest, and documentation about the DB connectors?

Comment: You could engage the folk in the #fabric-ledger channel on RocketChat https://rocketchat.hyperledger.org/. We haven't specific documentation, but there are design specs that those in the channel might be able to refer you to